# Generic function declaration in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create some stats about method call duration in a library.
Instead of wrapping each method call to the library with lines to time and track it, I want to create a generic action and function which does these recurring steps.

E.g. for methods that don't return a value, I have created this:

```
    private readonly Action<string, Action> timedAction = (name, action) =>
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        action.Invoke();
        trackDuration(name, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    };
```

That can be invoked with `timedAction("methodname", () => lib.methodname())`.

I want to do something similar for methods that return a value, but obviously `Action` can't be used for that purpose, since it can't return a value.

Is there a way to do this with a generic `Func`, so I don't have to declare one for each combination of library method parameters?

Comment: You might want to look at AOP solutions like PostSharp for this type of thing.

Comment: Also, ponder the [Tuple.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.create(v=vs.110).aspx) method group. There's no way to write methods that accept an arbitrary number of generics.

Comment: The caller can trivially pass any call as an `Action` by just making it a statement: `timedAction("methodname", () => { lib.methodname(1, 2, 3); })`.

Comment: Calling methods just isn't generic.  Do avoid creating your own profiler, they already exist and don't work like this.

Comment: I think there are more elegant solutions to this problem. [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/MethodTimer) could be an option. Or you could create your own solution involving [interception](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) (depending on your architecture using interception can be really easy or really hard/impossible).

Comment: you know you can get the method name from the property, for ex: `action.Method.Name`. Also, is it necessary to call using lambda? simply calling `timedAction("methodname", lib.methodname)` is enough...

Comment: I'll throw in my two cents by mentioning that I have used code like this in production. If all you need to do is time a few long-running actions in a production service and log that, then a profiler is inappropriate and a new tool/framework can be severe overkill. The added overhead of the delegate call means you can't use this to time short-running methods that are frequently called; that sort of thing still warrants profiling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a generic function like this:

```
private static TValue FuncHandler<TValue>(string name, Func<TValue> func)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var result = func();

    trackDuration(name, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    return result;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var result = FuncHandler("name", () => MyMethod(param1));
```

Comment: The return value of `func()` is always of type `TValue` i dont think you need to cast there.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. I thought I had to specify a placeholder on `FuncHandler` for the input parameters of the method that should be timed, but this works great.

Comment: If you use anonymous lambda it works, actual function call is wrapped in the lambda. Just make sure you have closure for all the parameters which might require closure. If you would use FuncHandler("name", MyMethod, param1); Then you would need to have both Func<TParameter, TValue> func and TParameter parameter as the parameters for FuncHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, AOP will buy you more than this sort of tediousness:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/5PLCmM

```
// Needs to be replicated after Func<T1, TResult>, Func<T1, T2, TResult>, etc, for all the functions arities you'll want to wrap with it
public static TResult Timed<T1, /*T2, etc*/TResult>(out long duration, Func<T1, /*T2, etc*/TResult> func, T1 arg1/*T2 arg2, etc*/)
{
    //start timing
    var t0 = DateTime.Now;
    var result = func(arg1/*, arg2, etc*/);
    //end timing
    duration = (long)DateTime.Now.Subtract(t0).TotalMilliseconds;
    return result;
}

public int Factorial(int n)
{
    return n > 0 ? n * Factorial(n - 1) : 1;
}

public int Fibonacci(int n)
{
    return n > 1 ? Fibonacci(n - 2) + Fibonacci(n - 1) : n;
}

public static void Main()
{
    var program = new Program();

    long duration;

    var _12bang = Timed(out duration, program.Factorial, 12);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}! = {1} in {2} ms", 12, _12bang, duration);

    var fib31 = Timed(out duration, program.Fibonacci, 31);

    Console.WriteLine("Fib {0} = {1} in {2} ms", 31, fib31, duration);

}
```

(yes, I know about StopWatch; was just too lazy to put it in there)

'Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot possibly see why you would replace OP's existing `Stopwatch` code with a `DateTime`, and call that additional step laziness.

Comment: @Groo. I was also on my phone and dotnetfiddle kept crashing on me with the system diagnostics namespace. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your case AOP will be more tedious. Here is my solution which works:

[image]

Class1.cs

```
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
public class Class1
{
    public void WriteNoParam()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("void");
    }

    public void WriteWithParam(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My name is: " + name);
    }
}
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Reflection;
    using ClassLibrary1;

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var prReflection = new TestReflection<Class1>();
        var elapsed = prReflection.TestFunc(new Class1(), @"C:\Users\yasir\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll", "WriteNoParam", new string[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time for non parameter method: "+elapsed);

        elapsed = prReflection.TestFunc(new Class1(), @"C:\Users\yasir\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll", "WriteWithParam", new[]{"Yasir"});
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time for parameter method: " + elapsed);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}

public class TestReflection<T> where T: class
{
    public Func<T, string, string, string[], long> TestFunc = (arg1, s, s2, arr) =>
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(s);
        var type = assembly.GetType(typeof (T).ToString());

        long executionTime;
        if (type != null)
        {
            var methodInfo = type.GetMethod(s2);

            if (methodInfo != null)
            {
                ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
                object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);

                var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                if (parameters.Length == 0)
                {
                    // This works fine
                    stopWatch.Start();
                    methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, null);
                    return stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                }
                stopWatch.Start();
                methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, arr); ;
                return stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    };
}
}
```

I have run in debug mode to test if the console is able to output in milliseconds and it works.

**If you don't run in debug, execution will be really fast and console will output 0.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this question already has an answer, but I think this solution can be interesting, if you don't want to have to pass the name, yourself, each time, you could do this:
(It was a lot inspired by @selami' answer.)

```
private MemberInfo GetMethodName<T>(Expression<T> expression)
{
    Expression body = expression.Body;
    // You might want to complete this
    // depending on which expression you want to use
    return ((MethodCallExpression)body).Method.Name;
}

// Works for both Action and Func
private object TimedMethodInvoke<T>(Expression<T> funcExpression)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var result = ((Delegate)(object)funcExpression.Compile()).DynamicInvoke();

    trackDuration(GetMethodName(funcExpression), sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    return result;
}
```

And your final methods:

```
public void TimeMethod(Expression<Action> actionExpression)
{
    TimedMethodInvoke(actionExpression);
}

public TValue TimeMethod<TValue>(Expression<Func<TValue>> funcExpression)
{
    return (TValue)TimedMethodInvoke(funcExpression);
}
```

*I didn't run a benchmark over this solution, but I guess you should encounter a little performance hit, but if you don't mind about that and want to avoid to type the name each time, this could help.*